# Updating the array object in React state using immutability helper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I am updating an object within an array in React state using [immutability helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

The object I want to modify is nested:

```js
this.state = {
  a: {
    b: [{ c: '', d: ''}, ...]
  }
}
```

I want to update the prop c within the nth element of b using immutability helper.

The equivalent code without the immutability helper is:

```js
const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
newState.a = Object.assign({}, newState.a);
newState.a.b = newState.a.b.slice();
newState.a.b[n] = Object.assign({}, newState.a.b[n]);
newState.a.b[n].c = 'new value';
this.setState({ newState });
```

I know the above code is a bit ugly. I am assuming the code using immutability helper will solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Consider using ImmutableJS.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

One way to do it would be using `$set`

```
let index = 0;
let newState = update(this.state, {
   a: {
     b: {
      [index]: {
               c: { $set: "new value"}
       }
    }
  }
});
this.setState(newState);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/61162/)

Comment: Does update return a new object/element like abc = Object.assign({}, xyz) or it changes the object given as parameter in place??

Comment: @VrajSolanki For this example, it will return new state object, with new `a` object (rest keys are the same, old references), with new `b` array in it, all of the element refernces wont be changed but `[index]` one. And with new reference for `c`, the rest will be old references.

Comment: @VrajSolanki the $set command will "replace the target entirely". The $merge command will merge the keys of `object` with the target.

https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#available-commands

Comment: Don't forget to import "update" from immutability-helper.

import update from 'immutability-helper';

Answer (score 9):

Im importing `update` from immutability helper here :)

```
this.state = {
  a: {
    b: [{ c: '', d: ''}, ...]
  }
} 


this.setState((prevState, props) => update(prevState, {
    a: {
        b: {
            $apply: b => b.map((item, ii) => {
                if(ii !== n) return item;
                return {
                    ...item,
                    c: 'new value'
                }
            })
        }
    }
}))
```