# Update array object in React Redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

This should be simple but I'm not finding the simple answer I want. I have a reducer:

```
const posts = (state = null, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "PUBLISH_POST":
        return state;
    case "UNPUBLISH_POST":
        return state;
    default:
        return postList;
  }
}
```

I have a list of posts with `ID`'s and a `status`. I'm sending in my post ID but can't figure out the logic to simply update the `status` from 0 to 1 for the item which has been clicked. I've found plenty of half-solutions but they all seem verbose and ugly - what's the shortest/best way of achieving it in this case?

Example data:

```
{
    id:1,
    user:"Bob Smith",
    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vulputate mauris vitae diam euismod convallis. Donec dui est, suscipit at dui vitae, sagittis efficitur turpis. ",
    status:1 
}
```

Comment: How does you state look like? Is it an array of posts?

Comment: @mersocarlin yes, example above

Comment: What is the action payload?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming your `action` is something like:

```
{
  type: 'UNPUBLISH_POST',
  payload: {
    id: 1,
    user: 'Bob Smith',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vulputate mauris vitae diam euismod convallis. Donec dui est, suscipit at dui vitae, sagittis efficitur turpis. ',
    status: 1
  }
}
```

Simply use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for it:

```
const posts = (state = null, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "PUBLISH_POST":
    case "UNPUBLISH_POST":
        const index = this.state.findIndex(post => post.id === action.payload.id)

        return [
           ...state.slice(0, index), // everything before current post
           {
              ...state[index],
              status: action.type === 'PUBLISH_POST' ? 1 : 0,
           },
           ...state.slice(index + 1), // everything after current post
        ]
    default:
        return postList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to remove "this." from the state. I realise I can not just do a toggle as well, rather than two conditions.

Comment: @MattSaunders you're welcome. I just noticed your `state` defaults to `null`. Maybe initialize it as an empty array so you don't have future problems with it :)

Comment: You might also consider using the [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) module along with the pattern described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276907/updating-the-array-object-in-react-state-using-immutability-helper).

Comment: thankss for the slice method, really useful with redux ;)

Comment: thank you man, it's really helpful

Comment: Like me, in case someone else is wondering if `state.slice(index + 1)` will error out if `index` belongs to the last element in the array, the answer is no. The `slice` method simply returns an empty array (`[]`) if the index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 8):

A more general solution, especially if state contains other data besides your `posts` array:

```
const posts = (state = null, action) => {
  const post = state.posts.find(p => p.id === action.payload.id);
  switch(action.type) {
    case "PUBLISH_POST":
      return { ...state, posts: [ ...state.posts.filter(p => p !== post), { ...post, status: 1 } ] };
    case "UNPUBLISH_POST":
      return { ...state, posts: [ ...state.posts.filter(p => p !== post), { ...post, status: 0 } ] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you'd want to return `filter(p => p !== post)` and the post to update?

Comment: @KerSplosh You're absolutely right, thanks. Updated the answer according to your comment.

Comment: Won't this mutate the order of the posts array though?

Comment: @slavlazar Yes it will. If you need to preserve order then use mersocarlin's solution using `slice`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have an array of posts, you can search for the ID of the post you want to modify and then update it.

Your initial state:

```
const initial = {
   posts: [],
}
```

Your reducer:

```
case MODIFY_POST:
        return {
            ...state, //Returns the current state
            posts: state.posts.map(post=> post.id === action.id ? // Loop through the array to find the post you want to modify
                { ...post, status: action.status} : post // Copy the post state and then modify it. Else return the same object.
            )
        }
```

Now, in your actions you can have two actions to toggle the status:

```
export const enablePost= (post_id) => {
return {
    type: MODIFY_POST,
    id: post_id,
    status: 1
    }
}
export const disablePost= (post_id) => {
return {
    type: MODIFY_POST,
    id: post_id,
    status: 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the spread operator on your state and it will automatically update it the way you want.

example:

```
    import { GET_ALL_PENDING_DATAOPS, CHANGE_DATAOPS_ASSIGNED_TO } from "../Actions/types";
const initialState = {
  requests: null
};
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_ALL_PENDING_DATAOPS:
      return {
        ...state,
        requests: payload
      };
      case CHANGE_DATAOPS_ASSIGNED_TO:          
        return {
          ...state,      
          requests:payload         
        }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My CHANGE_DATAOPS_ASSIGNED_TO action maps the previous state, in my axios call i am updating a single request object out of an array of requests, since it is returning a single object, and i am not explicitly returning that as just the state, I am using spread, it updates only that object and leaves the rest alone.

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer. Can you please include your code within the answer instead of as an image? Posting screenshots of code is bad practice on Stack Overflow.