# Using React Hooks useReducer, how can I update an object by ID efficiently?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/todos-usereducer-hook-ericb-stackoverflow-question) that you can fork, I found a similar answer but I'm having trouble applying it to my example, I think it's because I have an array of objects.

I have the code working but it's very verbose, and I would like something easier to read that others who use Redux will recognize.

```
const initialState = [];
const todoReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO': {
      return [...state, {
        id: state.length,
        name: action.name,
        complete: false
      }];
    }
    case 'TOGGLE_COMPLETE': {
      let left = state.filter((_, index) => index < action.index)
      let right = state.filter((_, index) => index > action.index)
      let completed = state.filter((_, index) => index == action.index)
      let updatedItem = {
        id: completed[0].id,
        name: completed[0].name,
        complete: !completed[0].complete
      }
      return [...left, updatedItem, ...right];
    }
    case 'CLEAR': {
      return initialState;
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    };
  }
}
```

I feel like the answer is is similar to this one? [Update array object in React Redux reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790746/update-array-object-in-react-redux-reducer)

In the answer I cited above, his object has `state.posts` How can I update my example to be more like this one?

How can I target my Todos if I don't have a similar state object as I can't do something like:

```
state.todos.complete = false.
```

I want to write a better reducer for the 'COMPLETE' action. Do I need to modify how my state is structured, ie dopes it need to be an empty object instead of an array of objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `map`:

```
case 'TOGGLE_COMPLETE': {
  return state.map((item, i) => i === action.index 
    ? {...item, complete: !item.complete}
    : item
  )
}
```

You can conditionally update "complete" without iterating multiple times.

Comment: Uhh, this was my first thought, let me try this out again.

Comment: Yeah i was forgetting to do the `..item, complete: true`

Comment: I also updated the example to use the `item.complete` and simply flip its value

Comment: @EricBishard glad it worked - sometimes just need a second set of eyes :). You can apply the same principle to your updated example. `{...item, complete: !item.complete}`

Comment: Thanks, I created an answered version of this on StackBlitz with the updated code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/todos-usereducer-hook-ericb-stackoverflow-answer

Comment: Thanks for doing that Damon! And thanks for the second set of eyes. lol