# How to update the state of array of objects from form fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a component that can be used for creating a new company record. A modal is opened with a form and the values are linked to the state values. In my situation, it will be possible to create more than one record of a company if the user chooses to add another company. A new company object will be pushed to the company state and the new empty form will be rendered.

This is what I've tried based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662708/react-updating-state-when-state-is-an-array-of-objects):

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Header, Form, Button, Icon, Tab, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class CompanyCreate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      company: [
        {
          name: '',
          segment: ''
        }
      ]
    };

    this.initialState = this.state;

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCompanyChange = this.handleCompanyChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value });

  handleCompanyChange = (e, { name, value }) => {
    const index = this.state.company.findIndex((x) => {
      return x[name] === value;
    });
    if (index === -1) {
      console.log('error');
    } else {
      this.setState({
        company: [
          ...this.state.company.slice(0, index),
          Object.assign({}, this.state.company[index], value),
          ...this.state.company.slice(index + 1)
        ]
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { company } = this.state;

    return (
      <Segment>
            {company.map((e, index) => (
              <Form size="large" key={index}>
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Input
                    width={6}
                    onChange={this.handleCompanyChange}
                    label="Nome"
                    placeholder="Nome"
                    name="name"
                    value={e.name}
                    required
                  />
                  <Form.Input
                    width={6}
                    onChange={this.handleCompanyChange}
                    label="Segmento"
                    placeholder="Segmento"
                    name="segment"
                    value={e.segment}
                    required
                  />
                 </Form.Group>
              </Form>
            ))}
          </Segment>
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is that I can't set the company state properly. How can you update the state in relation to the changes in the form fields?

Comment: Unless for the title there is no question or current problem mentioned? Neither is this a [mcve], so there is simply to much to implement, before we can try out your current problem

Comment: Sorry, the question and the code was updated. Please, help me.

Comment: That's a lot of code to test the update of a simple state. What is working and what is not? Have you checked you can get `event.target.value` from `(e, { name, value })`?

Comment: The first comment says there is not enough code. Now you say it's a lot of code.
If it's simple, please ... show me how to do it. If values were the problem, the question would be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for answers, I found the package: [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper). Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276907/updating-the-array-object-in-react-state-using-immutability-helper), the problem was solved simply and elegantly.

The solution:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

//...

this.state = {
  company: [
    {
      name: '',
      segment: ''
    }
  ]
};

//...

handleCompanyChange = (e, { name, value, id }) => {
  let newState = update(this.state, {
    company: {
      [id]: {
        [name]: { $set: value }
      }
    }
  });
  this.setState(newState);
};

//...

render() {
const { company } = this.state;

return (
  <Segment>
        {company.map((e, index) => (
          <Form size="large" key={index}>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Input
                width={6}
                onChange={this.handleCompanyChange}
                label="Nome"
                placeholder="Nome"
                name="name"
                value={e.name}
                id={index}
                required
              />
              <Form.Input
                width={6}
                onChange={this.handleCompanyChange}
                label="Segmento"
                placeholder="Segmento"
                name="segment"
                value={e.segment}
                id={index}
                required
              />
             </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        ))}
      </Segment>
  );
}
```